# Firebase user management and access level security rules (array-contains-any and in operators)

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have user accesses stored in an array of objects for my account documents accounts/{accountId}

```
access: [
{uid:"xyz123",level:"admin"}
{uid:"xyz456",level:"view"}
]
```

Can I setup a firestore rule with the in operator to check if user id requesting the data matches one of the objects in this access array.

This works in the simulator, but in the live app i'm getting permissions denied

```
match /accounts/{document=**} {
      allow read: if {"level":"owner", "uid":request.auth.uid} in resource.data.access;
      allow read: if {"level":"view", "uid":request.auth.uid} in resource.data.access;
      allow read: if {"level":"edit", "uid":request.auth.uid} in resource.data.access; 
      allow read: if {"level":"restricted", "uid":request.auth.uid} in resource.data.access; 

    }
```

I want to keep the accesses on the documents as they need to be document-based.

Answer (score 0):

The above works fine. I was missing admin level check as well in the security rules while in my call to database I had array-contains-any with this array

```
[{"level":"owner", uid},{"level":"admin", uid},{"level":"view", uid},{"level":"edit", uid}]
```

Here are the rules

```
allow read: if {"level":"owner", "uid":request.auth.uid} in resource.data.access;
      allow read: if {"level":"admin", "uid":request.auth.uid} in resource.data.access;
      allow read: if {"level":"view", "uid":request.auth.uid} in resource.data.access;
      allow read: if {"level":"edit", "uid":request.auth.uid} in resource.data.access; 
      allow read: if {"level":"restricted", "uid":request.auth.uid} in resource.data.access;
```

Whatever you put in the firestore request needs to be covered by your security rules.